# Why the control is not going inside foreach in following scenario?

Tags: php, html, foreach

The scenario is I'm fetching a record from MySQL database. This record data is in the form of HTML, so I want to remove few tags from this HTML data record. For this I wrote one function also. But I'm not getting why the control is not getting inside foreach. For your reference I'm giving below some part of the function:

```
function clear_question_data($html){ 
    $dom = new DOMDocument();

    $dom->loadHTML($html);

    foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $image)
    { echo "Inside Foreach"; die;
        $image->removeAttribute('alt');
        $image->removeAttribute('xmlns');
        $image->removeAttribute('title');
    }
            echo "Out of Foreach"; die;
        $txt=$dom->saveHTML();

        $dom->loadHTML($txt);

        foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $image)
        {
            $srcval=$image->getAttribute('src');

            $srcval = htmlspecialchars_decode($srcval);

            $srcval = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $srcval);  

            if(strpos($srcval,"%5C%22")==0)
            {           
                $srcval = str_replace("%5C%22", "", $srcval);
                $srcval = str_replace(".png%5C%22", ".png", $srcval);
            }
            if(strpos($srcval,"../../..")==0)
            {           
                $srcval = str_replace("../../..", "", $srcval);
            }
            if(strpos($srcval,"../..")==0)
            {           
                $srcval = str_replace("../..", "", $srcval);
            }
            if(strpos($srcval,"/ckeditor_3.6.1//plugins")==0) 
            {           
                $srcval = str_replace("/ckeditor_3.6.1//", EPN_SITE_URL."ckeditor_3.6.1/", $srcval);
            }


              $srcval = str_replace(".png/\"", ".png", $srcval);
              $srcval = str_replace("�", "-", $srcval);

            $image->setAttribute('src',$srcval);
        }   
        $final_data=$dom->saveHTML();

        return $final_data;
}
```

The sample Input data(i.e. `$html`) is as follows:

```
Glucose when hetaed with CH<sub>3</sub>OH in presence of dry HCl gas gives<img align=\"middle\" alt=\"«math xmlns=¨http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML¨»«mi»§#945;«/mi»«/math»\" class=\"Wirisformula\" src=\"/ckeditor_3.6.1//plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=dedbf6a559a928eeeaee82c4b1bf40d3.png\" title=\"Double click to edit\"> and <img align=\"middle\" alt=\"«math xmlns=¨http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML¨»«mi»§#946;«/mi»«/math»\" class=\"Wirisformula\" src=\"/ckeditor_3.6.1//plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=2c5cf4a4494a03be06d6c32308a225ba.png\" title=\"Double click to edit\">-methyl glycosides because it contains.<br>
```

Whenever I try to debug this function I'm getting a message "Out of Foreach" instead of "Inside Foreach". I'm not getting why this is happening. Can anyone help me in this regard please? Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. If you have any better way to achieve the result than foreach it's welcome.

Comment: Did you check if your html is loaded properly? something like `if($dom->loadHTML($html) === false) die('did not load');`

Comment: @jaudette:yES, I did check as you said, the HTML is loading perfectly without any issue.

Comment: It's working here with your data, so i cannot help much. Have you tried looking at `$dom->saveHTML()` before the foreach loop to make sure you have what you think you should?

Comment: What is the result of var_dump($dom->getElementsByTagName('img')) ?

Comment: I've modified my question now. Added complete function code of clean up. Now can anyone help me in detecting why the control is not going inside foreach?

Comment: @Patrick: It prints object(DOMNodeList)#12 (0) {
}

Answer (score 0):

altough you say is loading without issues, please try to load it like this, as the code is malformed:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```